# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un libro a una lista con un método? [JAVA]

Tags: java

tengo un método llamado `addLlibre` donde a partir de 3 parámetros que me pasan en el método, debo de añadir un libro.

Aquí está mi método:

```
public void addLlibre(String isbn, String titol, Date publicacio) {
        ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
        // TODO Añadir libros
        myList.add(isbn);
        myList.add(titol);
        myList.add(publicacio);
    }
```

Os muestro mi clase libro:

```
package pe1.llibres.autors;

import java.util.Date;

public class Llibre {
    protected String isbn;
    protected String titol;
    protected Date publicacio;
    protected Autor autor;

    public Llibre(String isbn, String titol, Date publicacio, Autor autor) {
        super();
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.titol = titol;
        this.publicacio = publicacio;
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String getTitol() {
        return titol;
    }

    public void setTitol(String titol) {
        this.titol = titol;
    }

    public Date getPublicacio() {
        return publicacio;
    }

    public void setPublicacio(Date publicacio) {
        this.publicacio = publicacio;
    }

    public Autor getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

}
```

Y en el `main`, creo un libro de la siguiente manera:

```
philip.addLlibre("978-84-0000002-0", "El hombre en el castillo", calendar.getTime());
calendar.set(1965, 2, 10);
```

Disculpad, no acabo de comprender cómo poder agregar un libro, soy consciente que haciendo esos 3 `.add` no se me añade, ya que estoy creado como si fuesen 3 libros, no 1 libro con 3 tipos de datos.

¿Alguien puede echarme una mano?

¡Un saludo y muchas gracias!

EDIT: En vez de con una lista, con un array.

Tengo este atributo de clase:

```
private Llibre[] llibres = new Llibre[MAX_LLIBRES];
```

Si quisiese añadir esos 3 parámetros (isbn, titol y publicacio) a este array, ¿cómo lo podría hacer? El método `.add` solo sirve en listas, ¿verdad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un par de cosas mal en el método addLlibre.

La primera que has mencionado es que estás añadiendo 3 entradas y además son strings en vez de libros. Esto te deja hacerlo porque no has especificado el tipo de lista que estás creando.

La segunda es que estás creando una lista nueva lista cada vez que llamas a addLlibre y luego no haces nada con ella, porque cuando acaba el método, esa variable local se manda al recolector de basura.

Para resolver el segundo problema, lo que tienes que hacer es declarar la lista como atributo de la clase. Es decir

```
protected List<Llibre> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Para resolver el primer problema, lo que tienes que hacer es añadir a la lista una única entrada de tipo Llibre. Esa entrada la tienes que aprovisionar con los datos que te llegan por parámetros. Sería algo así;

```
public void addLlibre(String isbn, String titol, Date publicacio) {
    Llibre llibre = new Llibre(isbn, titol, publicacio, null);
    myList.add(llibre);
}
```

Ojo que he puesto null como autor porque ese dato no lo tienes como parámetro en el método addLlibre. Esto podrá estar bien o mal dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer.

Por otra parte en lo del calendario, ten en cuenta que primero estás obtiendo el valor y luego estableciendolo. Debería ser al revés. Primerlo le das el valor y luego lo obtienes para crear el libro.

Si lo quieres hacer con arrays tienes que tener en cuenta que necesitarás una variable auxiliar para saber en qué posición tienes que insertar el siguiente valor, y además controlar que no añadas más libros de los que puede albergar el array. Es decir algo así:

```
private Llibre[] llibres = new Llibre[MAX_LLIBRES];
private int posicion = 0;
```

Cuando añadas tendrás algo así:

```
if (posicion >= MAX_LLIBRES) {
   throw new Exception("Superado el máximo de libros");
} else {
   Llibre llibre = new Llibre(isbn, titol, publicacio, null);
   llibres[posicion] = llibre;
   posicion++;
}
```

Comment: Entiendo ... Muchísimas gracias. ¿Y si quisiese hacer lo mismo pero en vez de meterlo en una lista, en un array ```llibres[]```? He editado mi pregunta, así te lo dejo más claro, graciaaas.

Comment: @AlexIglesias he modificado la respuesta añadiendo el supuesto de que los libros se guarden en un array.

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo, eres un crack!